# Generalised Likelihood Models

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, distributions

Why would you use a re-scaled binomial distribution rather than just the standard binomial distribution as the distributional assumption in a GLM?

Comment: to deal with over- or under-dispersion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because linear predictor is linked to the canonical link function on the terms of mean.

[Link function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function):- The link function provides the relationship between the linear predictor and the mean of the distribution function.

Natural Parameter should always be in terms of mean.

And the main point is we can't get Standard Binomial as Exponential family. Because dispersion parameter will stuck to $b(\theta)$ 'function of natural parameter'.

Comment: But if the scaled Binomial is an exponential family then the normal Binomial would be too? Since it's just a special case?

Comment: @misterE No! show me your workings I'll tell you flaw. Note:- you need natural parameter in terms of mean.

Comment: Well the scaled binomial distribution is $\frac{1}{m}$Bin$(m,\pi(x))$ where the natural parameter is $ln(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi})$ so if we just take $m=1$ this wouldn't change the natural parameter?

...Oh but I suppose that's not the same as the full binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes! It will good only for m=1 otherwise not.